# I'd like to extract specific fields from syslogs using grep or awk

Tags: linux, awk, grep

Here's an example of syslogs that I'm working on.  I'm trying to extract the `account_id` and `version_apk` fields from the syslogs:

```
Sep 16 06:59:16 as09 janus-server[as09][21840]: INFO: janus.application.application: 120:  audha6xnTESMSvpgr5n31Q== R: /rpc/v1/authentication/login({'api_key': 'f6ZO7j11myA8PA3M', 'encoded': True, 'password': 'ZGV2YTEyMzQ=\n', 'login_context': {'channel': 'CR_TN_2017', 'current_location': 'Anthiyur - Vellithiruppur Rd, Vellithiruppur, Tamil Nadu 638314, India', 'device_id': 'abbbecfc99323739', 'geolocation_status_flag': 'None', 'ip_address': '157.49.238.159', 'latitude': '11.6164226', 'long_session': False, 'longitude': '77.6226461', 'mac_address': 'None', 'platform': 'mobile_native_apk', 'postal_code': '638314', 'user_agent': 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; Redmi 8 MIUI/V11.0.1.0.QCNINXM)', 'version_apk': '2.3.7'}, 'username': '8903170787'}) => result({'session_id': 'bdd6d9c2469c43e2a0f28542485a7c5d', 'account_id': 2417963, 'username': 'esumk', 'site_code': 'FNIRNCZ', 'destroyed_other_sessions': True, 'forbidden': False, 'previous_login_time': 1600190099, 'device_type': 'mobile_native_apk', 'mac_address': 'None', 'ip_address': '157.49.238.159', 'current_location_latitude': '11.6164226', 'current_location_longitude': '77.6226461', '_caller_api_key': 'f6ZO7j11myA8PA3M', '_api_key': 'benga4eavoh1Ahn2', '_event': 'login', 'show_kyc_popup': False, 'kyc_bonus_popup_message': None, 'kyc_bonus_amount': {'Bonus_INR': 0}, 'front_key': 'paid_android_app', 'camp': {'eligible_status': False}, 'ask_geolocation': False})
```

I tried using:

```
grep 'login_context' | grep  "'platform': 'mobile_native_apk'" | grep "R."| grep "result" | grep -Po '(?<=version_apk.:)[^,}]+'
```

and the same for `account_id` as well but somehow the count of both differs.

I also tried using `awk`, but from the examples I saw the variables can be called out using $1, $2 or $35 (only with positions but not names).

The output i desire looks like this:

```
2.3.7   2417963
```

Which are nothing but version_apk and account_id for every syslog

Any better approach that I can prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with `sed` might help:

```
$ sed "s/^.*version_apk': '\([^']*\).*account_id': \([^,]*\).*$/\1 \2/" syslog
2.3.7 2417963
```

For each line this

- starts at the beginning of the line (`^`)
- matches 0 or more of any character (`.*`) until it gets to `version_apk: '`
- defines a group (`\(...\)`).  That group matches 0 or more characters that are not a single quote (the single quote that would end the version_apk value; `[^']*`).
- matches 0 or more of any character again (`.*`) until it gets to `account_id:`
- defines another group.  That group matches 0 or more characters that are not a comma (the comma after the `account_id`; `[^,]*`)
- matches 0 or more characters all the way to the end of the line (`.*$`)
- Replaces that entire match with the content of the first group, a space, and the content of the second group (`\1 \2`)

This assume that `version_apk` will always come before `account_id`.

Answer (score 0):

WIith GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/'login_context'/ && /'platform': 'mobile_native_apk'/ && /R./ && /result/ {
    delete f
    while ( match($0,/'([^']+)': ('[^']+'|[0-9]+)/,a) ) {
        f[a[1]] = gensub(/'/,"","g",a[2])
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print f["version_apk"], f["account_id"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2.3.7 2417963
```